# Counter example to an adaptation of the Riesz-Markov theorem.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $(K,\tau)$ is a topological space and that $\phi$ is a positive linear functional on $C(K)$. Then is it true that there exists a unique Baire measure $\mu$ on $K$ such that $\phi(f) = \int_K f\space d\mu$ for all $f\in C(K)$?

The original theorem asks for K to be compact and Hausdorff. But no where have I seen that this is actually needed. (I know a similar statement when dealing with Borel measure requires additional conditions).

The proof is too long to state here. If you have come across this before, I would appreciate your comments. And if you happen to have a counter example, then please do tell. But please do so in a gentle way, as I will be a broken man!

Comment: If $K$ is not compact, then you usual definition of $\sup$ norm does not work (it is not well defined)

Comment: Yes, I meant to replace $C(K)$ with $C_b(K)$. But subsequently I have actually realised there was a need for the condition of compact Hausdorff in a small step of my proof.

Comment: So you can answer your questioin or delete it

Answer (score 2):

To see the functional on $C_b(R)$ which is not represented by a measure on the real line consider a subspace $X$ of $C_b(R)$ of those functions which have the limit at $+\infty$.
Then $\varphi(g)=\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$ defines a functional on $X$. By the Hahn-Banach theorem $\varphi$ extends to a continuous functional $\varphi'$ on $C_b(R)$. Now it is easy to check that $\varphi'$ is not represented by a measure.

More generally, if $X$ is not compact (completely regular topological space)  then $C_b(X)$ is isometric to $C(\beta X)$ and every functional on $C_b(X)$ is represented by a measure which lives on $\beta X$ (the Stone-Čech compactification).